# Binding to DataContext Failing

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding

I have a wpf window that displays tasks.  The user clicks on a task in a TreeView control then other controls (TextBox, ComboBox, etc.) shows the various properties of the selected task.  I have implemented this as follows:

1) The TreeView is pupulated by:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsTasks}}"
```

2) The DataContext for the window is set in code-behind as follows:

```
Public Class Tasks
Private tsk As Task
....
Private Sub LoadMe(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
  DataContext = tsk
....
End Sub 

Private Sub SelectTask(sender As Object, e As RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs(Of Object)) Handles treTasks.SelectedItemChanged
  tsk = DirectCast(e.NewValue, Task)
End Sub
....
End Class
```

3) Each of the task properties use binding as shown below for the Description property:

```
<TextBox
    x:Name="txtDescription"
    AcceptsReturn="True"
    Text="{Binding Path=Description}">
</TextBox>
```

and that is what is not working.  None of the controls with binding show corresponding value when a TreeView item is selected by the user.

What an I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the private `tsk` field won't cause the view to refresh. Try to set the `DataContext` property in your event handler:

```
Private Sub SelectTask(sender As Object, e As RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs(Of Object)) Handles treTasks.SelectedItemChanged
  DataContext = DirectCast(e.NewValue, Task)
End Sub
```

Or make `tsk` a public property that you bind to and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for. This requires you to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface) interface.

Comment: My problem was not recognizing that setting tsk did not cause the view to refresh.  I also tried the other approach you suggest (tsk already has INotifyPropertyChanged) but changing to a new tsk when the user makes another selection from the TreeView also does not refresh the view.  Too bad because I think that is a more elegant approach.

Answer (score 0):

Please add Mode and UpdateSourceTrigger in your XAML.

```
Text="{Binding Path=Description,  Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [`ElementName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.elementname?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Consider this is your `TreeView` control

```xml
<TreeView x:Name="myTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsTasks}}">
    ...
</TreeView>
```

Then, binding at your `TextBox` will be like,

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=myTreeView, Path=SelectedItem.Description, Mode=TwoWay}"
         AcceptsReturn="True"/>
```